# Is there a way to filter out offensive words from Jcaptcha?

Tags: java, captcha

We are using JCaptcha for a captcha tool in a small app that my team is writing.  However, just during development time (on a small team - 4 of us), we've run across a number of curse words and other potentially offensive words for the actual captchas.  Is there a way to filter out potentially offensive words so that they are not presented to the user?

Comment: Every word is a "potentially offensive word" to somebody.

Comment: the point of captchas are that a program cannot 'read' them and figure out which word it is. Short of finding a different source for captchas I think your out of luck

Comment: @Holograham Yeah, I may be constrained to using JCaptcha, unfortunately, unless I can find other tool that I can package up & allows us to do the verifications on our own server.  We also need support for internationalization & 508 compliance (audio files), which JCaptcha does support.  I'm dealing with a very strict architecture group (sigh).  I'd love to use re-captcha (which, I believe, already has its own filters for this sort of thing), but the architecture group has nixed it.

Comment: @Will ... true, I guess. I'd like to at least try & filter out curse words in a few different languages & racial slurs (that's the kind of thing we're noticing).

Comment: I'm sorry but you guys are completely nuts to think it's not possible. There are at least **two** ways to do what the OP wants. You can either prevent CAPTCHA generation of unwanted words (which is **trivially easy** seen that you have access to JCaptcha's source) *OR* you can hash all the undesired *f!ck* and *s*ck* and *d#ck* words and put their hashes in a set and reject captchas that would hash to one of these. This is **trivial** to do and you guys commenting that "by design it's impossible" is *really* scary.

Comment: @Wizard: The point of at least ReCaptcha is, that it doesn't even know half of the words itself (All it has is the image!) Alright, I'm not 100% sure, if the same is true for JCaptcha.

Comment: @chris_l: but JCaptcha != ReCaptcha.

Comment: @Will -- yes, every word is potentially offensive.  That's why elduff wants to exert control.  Some people do tend to confuse "protecting others' freedom of speech" with "total passivity toward hatred, malice and vileness."  But others are able to distinguish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent time downloading JCaptcha and looking at the source. Basically JCatpcha works like *every single captcha out there besides ReCaptcha*. Hence what you want to is trivial.

JCaptcha is using the very simple concept of a WordGenerator, which is and interface:

```
public interface WordGenerator {
    String getWord(Integer length);
    String getWord(Integer length, Locale locale);
}
```

Let us ignore localization.

Typical use is like this:

```
WordGenerator words = ...
WordToImage word2image = new SimpleWordToImage();
ImageCaptchaFactory factory = new GimpyFactory(words, word2image);
pixCaptcha = factory.getImageCaptcha();
```

In their unit tests we can see, for testing purpose:

```
    WordGenerator words = new DummyWordGenerator("TESTING");
    WordToImage word2image = new SimpleWordToImage();
    ImageCaptchaFactory factory = new GimpyFactory(words, word2image);
    pixCaptcha = factory.getImageCaptcha();
```

Note that we have **ENTIRE** control on the "WordGenerator" used.

Here's one (working, fully functional) word generator I just wrote:

```
private static final Random r = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );

public String getWord( final Integer length ) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        final int rnd = r.nextInt( 52 );
        final char c = (char) (rnd < 26 ? 'a' + rnd : 'A' + (rnd-26));
        sb.append( c );
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It generates random "words" like these:

```
fqXVxId
cdVWBSZ
zXeJFaY
aeoSeEb
OuBfzvL
unYewjG
EhbzRup
GkXkTyQ
yDGnHmh
mRFgHWM
FFBkTLF
DvCHIIT
fDmjqLH
XMWSOpa
muukLLN
jUedgYK
FlbWARe
WohMMgZ
lmeLHau
djHRqlc
```

Note that if you prefer "real words" (like reCaptcha, but reCaptcha is using real word for another purpose altogheter -- because it helps scanning/OCRing books!) it's not an issue, simply change *getWord(...)* to pick randomly words out of a dictionary.

Now how do you prevent insulting words to be picked up? This is *trivial*. Here I just give one example (please, no arguing about the code, it's really just *one* example that shows how it *could* be done):

```
private static final Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();

static {
    s.add( "f**k" );
    s.add( "suck" );
    s.add( "dick" );
}

private static final Random r = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );

public String getWord( Integer length ) {
    String cand = getRandomWord( length );
    while ( isSwearWord(cand) ) {
        cand = getRandomWord( length );
    }
    return cand;
}

private boolean isSwearWord( final String w ) {
    return s.contains( w.toLowerCase() );
}

public String getRandomWord( final Integer length ) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        final int rnd = r.nextInt( 52 );
        final char c = (char) (rnd < 26 ? 'a' + rnd : 'A' + (rnd-26));
        sb.append( c );
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now if you want to prevent swear words, you probably *also* want to prevent those close to swear words (eg *"fvck"* and *"dikk"* etc.). This is once again trivial:

```
 private boolean isSwearWord( final String w ) {
    List<String> ls = generateAllPermutationsWithLevenhsteinEditDistanceOne(w);
    for ( final String cand : ls ) {
        if ( s.contains( cand.toLowerCase()) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Writing of the method *"generateAllPermutationsWithLevenhsteinEditDistanceOne(w)"* is left as an exercice to the reader.

Comment: @chris_l: your problem lies in your mind's failure to realize that when it comes to security there's an asymetry: the "defendant" has more infos available then the attacker. Your entire rambling is *exactly* identical to someone who would say *"PKCS ain't working because you can't multiply two huge prime numbers because you can't factor two huge prime numbers"*. Which is a completely circular argument that is *precisely* missing the whole point why PKCS works and why Captcha works. There **MUST** be a way to verify that an answer is correct (or incorrect). We have the words info on the server.

Comment: btw generating all the permutations that have an Levenhstein Edit Distance of one is easier than computing the edit distance itself.

Comment: Thanks @WizardOfOdds - this is the kind of thing I was hoping for a description of how to do, but you went above & beyond with a great detailed answer.

Comment: @elduff: I decided to delete the flamewar in the other post. I agree, Wizard answered your question well (+1).